# How to write umlaut and other non a-z characters in xfig

Tags: character-set

Using ubuntu 17.10, how can I write umlaut and other non a-z characters, like ö, in xfig?

Comment: See the [XFig User Manual section Compose-Chars](http://mcj.sourceforge.net/drawing.html#compose-char)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a new input source in Settings -> Region and Language